# Textured geometry loses image on lighting update

Tags: three.js, aframe

In this code I'm creating a scene with a 360 image textured sky and a small info icon that is meant to brighten when moused over. The scene begins with default lighting, and when the icon is moused over a different light source is added. When I try to remove the lighting object when the mouse moves out of the scene the original lighting from before the sphere light was added isn't restored. The icon goes completely dark when the mouse leaves and the icon's image texture is no longer visible. Can anyone explain what lighting arrangement or attribute on the icon I should use to keep it from losing visibility?

The code underneath is the src for the scene creation.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('mlisten',{
  init:function () {
    let el = this.el
    this.el.addEventListener('mouseenter',function() {
      let scene = document.querySelector("a-scene")
      let light = document.createElement("a-entity")
      light.id ="backlight"
      light.setAttribute("position","0 10 0")
      light.setAttribute("geometry",{
        primitive:"sphere",
        radius:"1"
      })
      light.setAttribute("material",{
        shader:"flat"
      })
      light.setAttribute("light",{
        type:"point",
        color:"#FFF"
      })
      scene.append(light)
    })
    this.el.addEventListener("mouseleave",function() {
      // remove light
      document.querySelector("#backlight").remove()
    })
  }
})




let basicScene = (room) => {
  let ob = {}
  ob.pointers =[] // this is the points of interest array will hold the objects
  ob.image = {} // structure will be name and path
  // the generic scene creation calls for aframe
  ob.create = ()=> {
    let scene = document.createElement("a-scene")
    scene.setAttribute("cursor","rayOrigin: mouse")
    // add rayOrigin mouse
    console.log("made scene")
    document.body.append(scene)
    let box = document.createElement("a-circle")
    box.setAttribute("position","0 0 -3")
    box.setAttribute("src","./resources/info.png")
    //box.setAttribute("geometry","primitive: circle; radius: 3")
    box.setAttribute("mlisten","")
    scene.append(box)
    //normal light

    scene.add(light)
    let sky = document.createElement("a-sky")

    let roomsImages = {
      "2181":"./resources/360-equirectangular.jpg",
      "2179":"./resources/gear-360_overview_bg.jpg",
      "2175":"./resources/DSCN0198.JPG",
      "2173":"./resources/Prague_Getty.jpg",
      "2169":"./resources/abu_06_big.jpg",
      "1347":"./resources/Venice.Still001.jpeg",
      "2171":"./resources/mountainscape-360_6.jpg",
      "2347":"./resources/01633841_20181218_Ocean_Terminal_Deck________360_____Tsim_Sha_Tsui__HK-1024x512.jpg",
      "2351":"./resources/01617830_ShibuyaCrossingView_360VR8K_h265-1024x512.jpg",
      "2349":"./resources/2A5E707000000578-3154678-image-a-27_1436438111376.jpg",
      "2353":"./resources/30279168385_925a9650ce_o.jpg"
    }
    sky.setAttribute("src",roomsImages[room])
    scene.append(sky)
    // just set static placed move and info icons
    // could include all the possible scenes again ordered by room icon
    // except that isn't going to stay around
    window.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=> {
      console.log(e)
      // remove the scene and go back to the previous view
      if (e.key === "Escape") {
        scene.remove()
      }
    })
  }
  return ob
}

//
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manipulating a light, manipulate the material of the object that you want to 'turn on'. Use the standard material (not flat), that has emissive (color) and emissiveIntensity (value). By bringing these (through animation or setAttribute) up to max (white and 1), the object appears fully emissive, like a video screen monitor).

Material standard properties from the manual
https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/material.html#standard

Comment: I just tried doing el.setAttribute("material",{emissive:1}) but the entity remains unchanged, did I mess something up?

Comment: oh, sorry emissive intensity is the numeric value.

Comment: yes, you will want to play with both to set the look that you want.